# Encog-c compile errors using vs2015 community

Tags: c++, visual-c++, neural-network, encog

I've downloaded the encog-c souce from http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/ and trying to compile them as instructed using vs2015 community.

When I build the solution I get the following errors:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

    Error   C2059   syntax error: 'sizeof'  encog-core  C:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\encog-c-master\encog-core\util.c 39  

    Error   C2059   syntax error: 'sizeof'  encog-core  C:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\encog-c-master\encog-core\util.c 44
```

and this linker problem:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

    Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual     Studio 2015\Projects\encog-c-master\Release\encog-core.lib'   encog-cmd   C:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\encog-c-master\encog-cmd\LINK    1
```

I don't sunderstand the error in the code (here's the code):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
int isnan(double x) 
{ 
    return x != x; 
}

int isinf(double x) 
{ 
    return !isnan(x) && isnan(x - x);     
}
#endif
```

For the linker error, I cannot find the encog-c-core.lib file so can't add it to the additional linker directories.

What am I doing wrong? What else needs setting up in the enviroment in order to compile the source.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Actually, I am mistaken. I downloaded the sources from https://github.com/encog not http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/ as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN documentation

- isnan https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzthab44.aspx
- isinf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh308344.aspx

since visual studio 2015, both functions are defined in the library. So, the workaround in `util.c` is not needed. Remove or comment out these definitions in `util.c`

```
/*
#ifdef _MSC_VER
int isnan(double x) 
{ 
    return x != x; 
}

int isinf(double x) 
{ 
    return !isnan(x) && isnan(x - x);     
}
#endif
*/
```

then recompile again. Hope this help.